# How do I enable EF migrations for multiple contexts to separate databases?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, database-migration

How do I enable Entity Framework 5 (version 5.0.0) migrations for multiple DB contexts in the same project, where each context corresponds to its own database? When I run `Enable-Migrations` in the PM console (Visual Studio 2012), there's an error because of there being multiple contexts:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
More than one context type was found in the assembly 'DatabaseService'.
To enable migrations for DatabaseService.Models.Product1DbContext, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName DatabaseService.Models.Product1DbContext.
To enable migrations for DatabaseService.Models.Product2DbContext, use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName DatabaseService.Models.Product2DbContext.
```

If I run `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName DatabaseService.Models.Product1DbContext` I'm not allowed to run `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName DatabaseService.Models.Product2DbContext` because a migration already exists: `Migrations have already been enabled in project 'DatabaseService'. To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter.`

Comment: Take a look at [Data Points - EF6 Code First Migrations for Multiple Models by Julie Lerman](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx)

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The 2nd call to Enable-Migrations is failing because the Configuration.cs file already exists.  If you rename that class and file, you should be able to run that 2nd Enable-Migrations, which will create another Configuration.cs.

You will then need to specify which configuration you want to use when updating the databases.

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName MyRenamedConfiguration
```

Comment: What is "MyRenamedConfiguration"?

Comment: "MyRenamedConfiguration" is just place holder text as an example.  You could have renamed your original Configuration.cs to anything, (e.g. FooBar, then run Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName FooBar).

Comment: shorten form:
Update-Database -conf MyRenamedConfiguration

Comment: Also I had to change ContextKey in MigrationHistory to the new namespace. Here is a good link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809668/14199515

Answer (score 106):

In addition to what @ckal suggested, it is **critical** to give each renamed Configuration.cs its own namespace.  If you do not, EF will attempt to apply migrations to the wrong context.

Here are the specific steps that work well for me.

If Migrations are messed up and you want to create a new "baseline":

1. Delete any existing .cs files in the Migrations folder
2. In SSMS, delete the __MigrationHistory system table.

Creating the initial migration:

1. In Package Manager Console:

   ```
   Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ContextTypeName
   NamespaceOfContext.ContextA -ProjectName ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne
   -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject  -ConnectionStringName ContextA
   ```
2. In Solution Explorer: Rename Migrations.Configuration.cs to Migrations.ConfigurationA.cs.  This should automatically rename the constructor if using Visual Studio.  Make sure it does.
   Edit ConfigurationA.cs: Change the namespace to NamespaceOfContext.Migrations.MigrationsA
3. ```
   Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ContextTypeName
   NamespaceOfContext.ContextB -ProjectName ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne
   -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject  -ConnectionStringName ContextB
   ```
4. In Solution Explorer: Rename Migrations.Configuration.cs to Migrations.ConfigurationB.cs.  Again, make sure the constructor is also renamed appropriately.
   Edit ConfigurationB.cs: Change the namespace to NamespaceOfContext.Migrations.MigrationsB
5. ```
   add-migration InitialBSchema -IgnoreChanges -ConfigurationTypeName
   ConfigurationB -ProjectName ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne
   -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject  -ConnectionStringName ContextB
   ```
6. ```
   Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigurationB -ProjectName
   ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject
   -ConnectionStringName ContextB
   ```
7. ```
   add-migration InitialSurveySchema -IgnoreChanges -ConfigurationTypeName
   ConfigurationA -ProjectName ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne -StartupProjectName
   NameOfMainProject  -ConnectionStringName ContextA
   ```
8. ```
   Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigurationA -ProjectName
   ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject
   -ConnectionStringName ContextA
   ```

Steps to create migration scripts in Package Manager Console:

1. Run command

   ```
   Add-Migration MYMIGRATION -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigurationA -ProjectName
   ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject
   -ConnectionStringName ContextA
   ```

   or -

   ```
   Add-Migration MYMIGRATION -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigurationB -ProjectName
   ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject
   -ConnectionStringName ContextB
   ```

   It is OK to re-run this command until changes are applied to the DB.
2. Either run the scripts against the desired local database, or run Update-Database without -Script to apply locally:

   ```
   Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigurationA -ProjectName
   ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject
   -ConnectionStringName ContextA
   ```

   or -

   ```
   Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigurationB -ProjectName
   ProjectContextIsInIfNotMainOne -StartupProjectName NameOfMainProject
   -ConnectionStringName ContextB
   ```

Comment: #4  change:  Edit ConfigurationA.cs  ->  Edit ConfigurationB.cs

Comment: @Biran: Thanks for noticing that.  I edited the answer. Note, you can edit answers yourself too.  Since you don't yet have 2000 reputation, your answers to into a review queue but that queue is usually worked through fast, so your edit would likely have been approved within a few minutes.

Comment: THANK YOU! That was what I was missing (the namespaces).

Comment: This may help because it wasn't clear to me how to do the renaming in **steps 2, and 4** initially: When you rename the Configuration.cs file to ConfigurationA.cs or ConfigurationB.cs, the renaming should also result in the class and its constructor being renamed to ConfigurationA or ConfigurationB too. Failure to rename the class will cause an error message when you run the add-migration command - **"The migrations configuration type 'ConfigurationA' was not be found in the assembly '...'"** - and yes, the wording was bad just like that in the error messages that I got in VS2013 - LOL

Comment: @GregBarth: Thanks for pointing that out.  When renaming the file in Visual Studio it should also rename the constructor (if you opt for refactoring to match the rename).  I updated the text to make it clearer.

Comment: this helped me! complete instructions with all the options and order. saved me hours

Comment: The renaming refs in the post & comments are not clear to me. The default configuration.vb created by enable-migrations has "Namespace Migrations" & ... "Class Configuration".  Is it correct to edit to "Namespace MigrationsA" & "Class ConfigrationA"? The 3rd comment up says to also rename the constructor, but the constructor is already named New() (in VB) - it wouldn't seem that needs renaming.

Comment: @Alan: In C#, the constructor has the same name as the class.  Each configuration needs a unique namespace.

Comment: @EricJ. is need to keep Migration folder(Configuration.cs and...) after do migration and update database fields???

Comment: If anything ever might change with the data model, yes. Next time the runtime detects a difference between the physical database and what the current model requires, it will look to the configuration to determine how to proceed. I don't see any upside of deleting it.

Comment: You Sir, have saved me countless hours of anguish in multiple projects. Thank you very much.

Comment: @caliche2000 Glad I could help you

Comment: In case it is not clear: If you already have one context and need to enable migrations for another one, then start at step 2, i.e., rename the existing `Configuration.cs` file. This is basically what the accepted answer says. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13477276/2279059

Answer (score 88):

I just bumped into the same problem and I used the following solution (all from Package Manager Console)

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -MigrationsDirectory "Migrations\ContextA" -ContextTypeName MyProject.Models.ContextA
PM> Enable-Migrations -MigrationsDirectory "Migrations\ContextB" -ContextTypeName MyProject.Models.ContextB
```

This will create 2 separate folders in the Migrations folder. Each will contain the generated `Configuration.cs` file. Unfortunately you still have to rename those `Configuration.cs` files otherwise there will be complaints about having two of them. I renamed my files to `ConfigA.cs` and `ConfigB.cs`

**EDIT**: (courtesy Kevin McPheat) Remember when renaming the Configuration.cs files, also rename the class names and constructors **/EDIT**

With this structure you can simply do

```
PM> Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigA
PM> Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigB
```

Which will create the code files for the migration inside the folder next to the config files (this is nice to keep those files together)

```
PM> Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigA
PM> Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigB
```

And last but not least those two commands will apply the correct migrations to their corrseponding databases.

**EDIT 08 Feb, 2016:**
I have done a little testing with EF7 version 7.0.0-rc1-16348

I could not get the -o|--outputDir option to work. It kept on giving `Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.Commandline.CommandParsingException: Unrecognized command or argument`

However it looks like the first time an migration is added it is added into the Migrations folder, and a subsequent migration for another context is automatically put into a subdolder of migrations.

The original names `ContextA` seems to violate some naming conventions so I now use `ContextAContext` and `ContextBContext`. Using these names you could use the following commands:
(note that my dnx still works from the package manager console and I do not like to open a separate CMD window to do migrations)

```
PM> dnx ef migrations add Initial -c "ContextAContext"
PM> dnx ef migrations add Initial -c "ContextBContext"
```

This will create a model snapshot and a initial migration in the `Migrations` folder for `ContextAContext`. It will create a folder named `ContextB` containing these files for `ContextBContext`

I manually added a `ContextA` folder and moved the migration files from `ContextAContext` into that folder. Then I renamed the namespace inside those files (snapshot file, initial migration and note that there is a third file under the initial migration file ... designer.cs). I had to add `.ContextA` to the namespace, and from there the framework handles it automatically again.

Using the following commands would create a new migration for each context

```
PM>  dnx ef migrations add Update1 -c "ContextAContext"
PM>  dnx ef migrations add Update1 -c "ContextBContext"
```

and the generated files are put in the correct folders.

Comment: the best solution, simple and we keep a clear folder.

Comment: This was the answer I needed.  The namespace added via -MigrationsDirectory was the answer!  Thank you.

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Thanks.

Comment: 1,5 year later, I am happy that I can use my own post to setup a new project.

Comment: Note when you run `add-migration` it will prompt you for `Name`. This threw me off slightly since I was already providing `ConfigurationTypeName` and got slightly annoyed when it just said `Name:`. But of course the Name it wants is the 'human readable' description of the change - eg. `AddedProducts` or `IncreaseLengthOfNameFields`. In the Migrations folder you'll get this as part of the class name so it's easy to see what is what. So in effect `Name` is kind of like a check-in comment.

Answer (score 8):

In case you already have a "Configuration" with many migrations and want to keep this as is, you can always create a new "Configuration" class, give it another name, like

```
class MyNewContextConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyNewDbContext>
{
   ...
}
```

then just issue the command

```
Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName MyNewContextConfiguration InitialMigrationName
```

and EF will scaffold the migration without problems. Finally update your database, from now on, EF will complain if you don't tell him which configuration you want to update:

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName MyNewContextConfiguration
```

Done.

You don't need to deal with Enable-Migrations as it will complain "Configuration" already exists, and renaming your existing Configuration class will bring issues to the migration history.

You can target different databases, or the same one, all configurations will share the __MigrationHistory table nicely.

Answer (score 6):

If more databases exist use following codes in PowerShell

```
Add-Migration Starter -context EnrollmentAppContext
```

- 'Starter' is Migration Name
- 'EnrollmentAppContext' is name of my app Context

You can open PowerShell in VS by doing:
`Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console`

Answer (score 5):

To update database type following codes in PowerShell...

```
Update-Database -context EnrollmentAppContext
```

*if more than one databases exist only use this codes,otherwise not necessary..