# EF5 Getting this error message: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have this error message that keeps on displaying every time I run the application. I'm using Entity `Framework 5: Code First`

Here's the error message,

```
System.NotSupportedException: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata)
   at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at LaundryService_DEMO.frmMain.btnCreate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\MyDocs\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LaundryService_DEMO\LaundryService_DEMO\frmMain.cs:line 39
```

This error started when I created an entity called invoice. Here's the full code of the entity,

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }

    public Customer CustomerField { get; set; }
    public SystemUser SystemUserField { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Invoice>
{
    public InvoiceMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(x => x.InvoiceID);

        // Property(ies) and Mapping(s)
        this.ToTable("Invoice");

        this.Property(x => x.InvoiceID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(15)
            .HasColumnName("InvoiceID")
            .HasColumnType("nVarchar");

        this.Property(x => x.CustomerID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(15)
            .HasColumnName("CustomerID")
            .HasColumnType("nVarchar");

        this.Property(x => x.UserID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(15)
            .HasColumnName("UserID")
            .HasColumnType("nVarchar");

        this.Property(x => x.TotalAmount)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("TotalAmount")
            .HasColumnType("decimal");

        this.Property(x => x.TransactionDate)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("TransactionDate")
            .HasColumnType("datetime");

        this.Property(x => x.PaymentDate)
            .IsOptional()
            .HasColumnName("PaymentDate")
            .HasColumnType("datetime");

        // Relationship
        this.HasRequired(x => x.CustomerField)
            .WithMany(x => x.InvoiceCollection)
            .HasForeignKey(y => y.CustomerID);

        this.HasRequired(x => x.SystemUserField)
            .WithMany(x => x.InvoiceCollection)
            .HasForeignKey(y => y.UserID);
    }
}
```

In order to replicate the application, I have included the project file which is [available for download](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16021179/LaundryService_DEMO.rar). And so this question will not be full of code.

If there are details that I've missed in the question, please comment so I can include it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I found the code working by changing

```
static LaundryShopContext()
{
  Database.SetInitializer<LaundryShopContext>(
    new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LaundryShopContext>());
}
```

into

```
static LaundryShopContext()
{
  Database.SetInitializer<LaundryShopContext>(
    new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LaundryShopContext>());
}
```

Comment: Just complete the answers:

The error is because you change your model after to run your code. You have 2 ways to fix it:

 1. You can change the logic of your database creating, how you did it in your answer;
 2. Or you can to start to use the Entity Framework Migrations, like the second answers;

Comment: Thanks... It worked. But it should have worked for me with `ifmodelchanges` because it has been working previously.

Comment: +1 for great hint. I think, though, that we're hiding the error, not resolving it. The problem with *IfModelChanges* is that it relies on the *_MigrationHistory* table. We're dodging the bullet by **always** creating the DB, hence not needing the history. However, once run with *Always*, the history table should be created, in my opinion. It doesn't in my case, though... I only see tables: *MSreplication_options*, *spt_fallback_db*, *spt_fallback_dev*, *spt_fallback_usg* and *spt_monitor*.

Comment: These database initializes are so bad solution....it can delete the data ....migrations should be a better solution, at least more safe.

Comment: @Pedigree, How can you mark this as answer when you changed the whole scheme from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LaundryShopContext>()` to `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LaundryShopContext>()`. Both schemes have totally different meaning. How can you mark it an aswer by changing the whole scenario. 
and @KonradViltersten when a new database is `Always` created, why would you expect it to make a `_Migration`(History) folder? I mean why would you need to know the history when a new database is already created?

Comment: @RehanKhan Now, it's been over a year so I can only speculate in what I meant. It seems to me, though, that creating a new DB can be done when an old DB already exists. You just drop and recreate it. For the DB's consideration, the history is meaningless because it thinks it's a new one. But the developer knows that there's been a DB there before.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yes there should be a way to create new db when an old db already exists. This is why `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` class is created but still getting this error is strange.

Comment: @RehanKhan Can't say for sure because it wasn't my question nor answer. However, I suspect that back then there might be something weird with the environments and that it's something like so, that glitched for him. No idea, really. Admittedly, it sounds a bit weird...

Comment: @KonradViltersten I am working on it. I will post it if i find something new or relevant.

Comment: Not applicable to SQLite as drop database not supported.

Comment: Wondering how in real life DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer and even more drastic DropCreateDatabaseAlways work. You mean forget about the "data" itself, just enjoy always well maintained maintain but "empty" database?

Answer (score 14):

This is probably related to your database not containing the _MigrationHistory table (which can be viewed using SQL Server Management Studio in Tables > System Tables).

Not sure how you are managing the database, but if you are still in development and using EF Migrations a quick solution is to delete the database and run Update-Database which will recreate the entire database and add the _MigrationHistory table.

If you want to avoid EF running this check you can add this to your DbContext class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this one. `IncludeMetadataConvention` is already obsolete on EF5. If you have downloaded the project I have lots of trial and error included there. Anyway, I greatly appreciate your answer.

Comment: I've tried this suggestion and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: i wonder how can you advise to delete a database. Suppose don't have the luxury to delete the database and suppose for the sake of getting this issue resolved, you do delete the database at this stage and get things done and same problem happens after 3 years and at that stage you don't have the luxury to delete the database .. what happens then?

Comment: another issue could be, suppose you have a database first approach for accessing a few tables within the same database you have codefirst approach. so deleting the database for the sake of codefirst solution meaning deleting the edmx context class and entities??? this is no solution.

Comment: I use localdb, ***mdf*** file in App_Data folder

Answer (score 12):

If, like me, this is caused by starting with Code First and changing to Database First development mid-project.. this is all caused by one simple line. If you need to keep your database and its data comment out the following line:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
```

from this section of your Model.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        //   Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

This will happen often in when starting out with the built in identity models. Once you get them working, you can remove that line to keep it intact yet retain the functionality. If your model changes, however, your database will have to be configured to match.. something you are doing in Database First development anyway!

Comment: I had this exact problem. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: THANKS! this should be at least also the correct answer to this question. I had the same situation: changing from code first to db first mid project

Answer (score 10):

This can also happen if you are trying to initialise the context against a previously existing database of the same name but that was created with another codebase.
This is why changing from DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges to DropCreateDatabaseAlways works, the latter configuration causes the database to be recreated no matter what, bypassing any sort of database versioning that might be causing this issue.

Comment: I had this situation too.  I changed it to Always, ran it, then changed it back to IfModelChanges.  Working fine now.

Comment: It does happen even when using identical code-first model. Encountered this problem when running two apps, one of which did not have *db_owner* role and was throwing the exception (even though the _MigrationHistory existed, DB was created the other app using EF **same** codebase).

Comment: I use localdb, mdf file in App_Data folder

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm late to the party, but I just came across the same error, and my database already had a migration history table.

The error might also indicate an incorrect context key in the history table. This may happen if you move the database context class to another namespace, like I did while refactoring.

**Updating the `ContextKey` value in the `MigrationHistory` table to the new namespace of the database context fixed the issue for me**.

This solution does not require you to discard the database contents so may be preferred over the `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` solution.

Comment: Bless you! This happened to me too as I moved my data code out of my domain project and into its own project with a different namespace! Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect! That fixed my problem. Check this link out for instructions on how to change the ContextKey. https://mitchelsellers.com/blog/article/handling-namespace-and-class-changes-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I add
`ContextKey = "MyProject.Repository.Common.DbContextA";`

to Configuration.cs. After remove that line, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below 3 steps . 
It works for me.. Run the following commands in package manager console
1. enable-migrations
2. update-database -verbose
3. add-migration initialmigrations -ignorechanges

NOTE: My scenario is I already created the db/tables (using code first approach (using a shared DB context library). I trying to use the library in another application and another database. I manually synched the first db into second.. thats why i encountered this problem.

Answer (score -3):

```
CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.