# How can i solve a "Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata" error?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I’m trying to connect to a remote server from within my project using this connection string :

```
  Data Source=myServer.com,14330;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User username;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I got this error message:

Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

If my remote database, SQL 2008 R2, does not have a metadata model, should I create one to make it compatible with the metadata of my local database during development?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF5 Getting this error message: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064434/ef5-getting-this-error-message-model-compatibility-cannot-be-checked-because-th)

Answer (score -1):

I removed references to the initializer class that I used to seed my local database.