# Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I create new database and run migration tool but it give that error

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

it give that error in that (code)line

```
if (db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
```

and this is my context

```
static DernekContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DernekContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DernekContext>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IncludeMetadataConvention>();    
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
          }
        }
```

there are many similar question in here i tried reCreate and all solution but it still give that error

Comment: Why do you remove the `IncludeMetadataConvention`?

Comment: @LukasKabrt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064434/ef5-getting-this-error-message-model-compatibility-cannot-be-checked-because-th in that last answear said....but with that line or without it give same error