# Why Model compatibility cannot be checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I had to work further from a ex collega. So I run the asp.net solution without database. and it created a database. I think this is Code First or Code First Migrations.

Then I tried some tests in de UI and get this message:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Model compatibility cannot be checked because
>   the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can
>   only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First
>   Migrations.

This is the code where de message come from.

```
public class TemInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public override void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            base.InitializeDatabase(context);
        }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve this or where i need to look?

Comment: Have you seen/tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064434/ef5-getting-this-error-message-model-compatibility-cannot-be-checked-because-th) ?

Comment: You can disable compatibility checking, but given this was not already done; it is probably better to fix it. EF will create an extra table with the details of the schema in it: so start by looking for system table `_MigrationHistory`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` initializer drops and recreates the database if the database schema no longer matches the classes in your code. It determines "if model changes" by looking at your classes and by looking at a table called `_MigrationHistory` in the database. If there is no such table, it throws the exception in the question.

So to solve this, you can:

- Use a different initializer (such as `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`) or
- Make sure that there is a `_MigrationHistory` table in your database, by enabling [Entity Framework code first migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

Comment: Thx i've do it with DropCreateDatabaseAlways. and then change back to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges.