# Disabling migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-model-first

I'm writing a web api attached to a database that I created using Model First.

Being new I was confusing Model First with Code First.

As it's my first EF/Web app I didn't realize that migration wasn't yet implemented by Model First and I followed the procedure to implement it. When it ran I received some errors, looked them up and only then realized I'd need to remove it again.

Following somebody's instructions I deleted the migrations folder, plus the _migrationHistory table from the database.

But now I receive the following exception whenever the _migrationhistory table is missing from the database.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
  // Call initializer
  Database.SetInitializer(new PulseDbInitializer());
  new ApplicationDbContext().Database.Initialize(true); <- error here

  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
  FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

*"An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations."*

The following is a partial description of my initializer

```
public partial class PulseDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>, IPulseDbInit
//public partial class PulseDbInitializer :DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>, IPulseDbInit
{
  private ApplicationDbContext _context;
  protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
    var pid = new PulseDbInitializionData(context);
    pid.Init(this);
  }
}// class PulseDbInitializer
```

It seems that the app is trying to use migrations (because it's creating the _migrationhistory table) even though I've removed the migrations subfolder.
Being new at this, I'm not sure where to go. I'm aware that I've created my initializer, see above, so am I missing something?

## EDIT - Too long for a comment

Im not sure we're understanding each other.

Very simply, I don't know what's generating the _MigrationHistory table in my database as afaik if I remove the Migration subdirectory from my project and delete the database, then I thought that's all I need to do to drop migrations.

In my model first, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges is what I've always used for generating the database and is working as expected. It creates a new database, or recreates when the model changes.

Until I added the migration I didn't notice this _MigrationHistory table and I don't have a clue if the add-migration command added any code to my project that I need to delete or change (I really hate things happening and not being told exactly what was done in some kind of log. Please microsoft, for future reference)

Or am I totally wrong and the _MigrationHistory table was always there but I never noticed? It all seems to work, as long as I don't remove the table.

Comment: The DropCreateDatabaseAlways that you have commented out should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349443/why-model-compatibility-cannot-be-checked

Comment: @SteveGreene yes, but that'd drop and recreate the database on every initialization, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, run it once then switch back to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Answer (score 0):

Your initializer is inheriting from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, which checks for model changes. Since you are not using code first you can't check for model changes in code (since your code doesn't define the model -that'd be code-first-... the model defines the code -that's model-first-)... so you need to implement your own `IDatabaseInitializer` which only checks (for example) that the database exists:

```
public partial class PulseDbInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>, IPulseDbInit
{
  public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
  {
    var exists = new DatabaseTableChecker().AnyModelTableExists(context.InternalContext);
    if (exists == DatabaseExistenceState.Exists)
    {
       // maybe check if certain data exists and call the `Seed` method if
       // it doesn't
       return;
    }

    // Throw some error if it doesn't exist
  }

  protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
    var pid = new PulseDbInitializionData(context);
    pid.Init(this);
  }
}
```