# System.NotSupportedException - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC project that's intended to list data from an SQL table; I'm not that experienced so I've been using the MSDN tutorial as a reference:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

My project works more or less the same, just with different variable names, I want a list of items that I can view/edit/add/delete.

The error shortly after the step where I had to create a scaffold.  I ran the project at step 5 where the list is expected to render at that point, but I got this error:

[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlmEg.png)

Not really sure what's wrong?

**Context.cs**

```
public class TimesheetContext : DbContext
{
    public TimesheetContext() : base("TimesheetContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Clients> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please insert a code snippet from which will start tech support (Specially, where you are setting up the DataContext) :) Also, make sure the DB structure is created

Comment: Regularly this happens when first time start using EF ;) this can help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064434/ef5-getting-this-error-message-model-compatibility-cannot-be-checked-because-th