# An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is my code:

```
using (var dbcontext = new ProjectContext())
     dbcontext.table1.Find(1);
```

When I run it, I am encountering this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Detailed Error:

```
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.
```

stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.ModelCompatibilityChecker.CompatibleWithModel(InternalContext internalContext, ModelHashCalculator modelHashCalculator, Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at Journals.Repository.DataContext.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor() in C:\Users\Arya\Desktop\Crossover\Source\Journals.Repository\DataContext\SimpleMembershipInitializer.cs:line 12
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try updating your EntitFramework from nuget in a new project and check

Comment: This probably won't matter, but have you tried assigning a variable to the returned value? E.g. `var found = dbcontext.table1.Find(1);`

Comment: please include the stacktrace of the exception (and possibly further 'InnerException's)

Comment: Entity framework updated but didnt work

Comment: yes i tried to use variable but that didnt work either

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064434/ef5-getting-this-error-message-model-compatibility-cannot-be-checked-because-th

Comment: I tried this as well...but this will remove the error, but removed all the data from my tables...