# Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata for AspNet Identity Models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

Error Coming for identity models
[image]

Comment: Have you made a migration and applied it to your database?

Comment: This might be of some help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064434/ef5-getting-this-error-message-model-compatibility-cannot-be-checked-because-th