# Enable Migrations in Multi-Tier MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am creating a new application using MVC 5 (Razor Views), Entity Framework 6 (Code First), ASP.Net Identity 2.0 and Web API.  Trying to create a decent de-coupled architecture, I wanted to enable migrations in my data layer, but I have a misunderstanding of how migrations work.  Here's my basic solution architecture:

```
MyApplication Solution
|-Domain Project
    |-Entity1
    |-Entity2
    |-Entity3
|-Data Layer Project (References Domain Project)
    |-DbContext (Inherits from IdentityDbContext)
|-Migrations Folder
|-Service Layer Project (Web API)
|-Business Layer Project
|-MVC Project
    |-Views
```

As shown above, the Data Layer Project I have enabled migrations by executing the Enable-Migrations command in the Package Manager Console.  The problem is, it only scripts the models related to Identity (AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserLogins, etc.).  How does a migration know to include an entity?  I need it to script the models in my Domain project and not quite sure how to tell EF/Migrations to do so.

**UPDATE:**
Per a request, my simple (out-of-the-box via scaffolded by new project) DbContext class below:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static MyDbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u show your DataContext class also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, it only scripts the models related to Identity
>   (AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserLogins, etc.). How does a migration know
>   to include an entity?

The migration "knows" what to script as it scripts on a per context basis. Look at the `Configuration.cs` class in the Migrations folder and you will notice that it is a generic class with the `DbContext` type passed in as follows:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
```

So it "knows" because you're explicitly telling it by passing in a `MyDbContext` generic type parameter.

So if you want to add your own entities classes for migration then you should have a `DbSet` for each of the entities in your `DbContext`. i.e.

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {

    public DbSet<Entity1> Entity1s {get;set;}

    public MyDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false){}

    public static MyDbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDbContext();
    } }
```

If you don't want to reuse MyDbContext for your custom entites then you can create another context, and add your entity `DbSet`s to that. But then you will have to explicitly enable and update the migrations as per [How do I enable EF migrations for multiple contexts to separate databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469881/how-do-i-enable-ef-migrations-for-multiple-contexts-to-separate-databases)