# Extending AspNetUsers table with migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to add additional fields to the AspNetUsers table created by Asp.NET Identity. I am using Entity Framework and am following this guide. http://aspmvp.com/archives/37

So far I have added fields to my ApplicationUser class within IdentityModels.cs.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int TimePlayed { get; set; }
    public float RevenueGenerated { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteCharity { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteGame { get; set; }
    public string ImageLocation { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I have also changed the fields needed to register in AccountController.cs, but I don't think that is going to affect how this works.

Right now I am trying to migrate the changes to my database, but for some reason the migrations being created by Add-Migration have an empty Up and empty Down. The commands I have used are:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations
Update-Database
```

Then I tried

```
Add-Migration IdentityModels
Update-Database
```

Both created the empty Up and Down methods in the migration.
When I try to launch the site I also see that the columns don't exist, but I am assuming that is because the migration isn't occurring. Does anyone see why my changes aren't being detected.

Comment: Have you updated your AppDbContext to reflect these changes? If you haven't changed the AppDbContext then the up and down methods will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

How manay database do you have? If you are using two databases, make sure you are pointing to the right one. `Enable-Migrations,Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName DatabaseService.Models.MyDbContext` as pointed out in [How do I enable EF migrations for multiple contexts to separate databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469881/how-do-i-enable-ef-migrations-for-multiple-contexts-to-separate-databases)

Also, If you are having two databases, i would suggest merging them into one,

```
public class MySecondDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public SocialContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -Force when adding the migration.

Add-Migration -configuration yourapp.migrationsfolder.Configuration migrationname-Force