# Using Entity Framework Migrate.exe with multiple migration configurations?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using migrate.exe and the error I'm getting is:

ERROR: More than one migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'myfile'. Specify the name of the one to use.

However, when I add the /ContextTypeName:nameOfContext, then it gives the following error:

ERROR: The migrations configuration type 'ContextTypeName:nameOfContext' was not be found in the assembly 'myfile'.

I'm sure the contextType exists and I've spelled it properly, but I keep getting this error. Has anyone else encountered this situation or could tell me what I could be missing?

Comment: which version of EF you are using?

Comment: EntityFramework6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you have to provide the configuration name in your command line:

```
PM> Add-Migration -ConfigurationTypeName YourDbConfig
PM> Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName YourDbConfig
```

Here you will find a good description [How do I enable EF migrations for multiple contexts to separate databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469881/how-do-i-enable-ef-migrations-for-multiple-contexts-to-separate-databases)