# Create two types of Users i.e Patient and Doctor in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core Web App and i need to make 2 Users: A Patient User and A Doctor User. With different login forms. They both inherit from IdentityUser. How do I handle the DbContext Migration?

As it stands now, I have two Classes that both inherit from IdentityUser : Patient and Doctor. The inherited classes each have different additional properties.

I have two DbContext Classes that inherit from DbContext to handle both Patient and Doctor.

When I try to Add-Migration it notices the two Migrations and tells me to specify which dbcontext class i am trying to migrate.

My questions are as follows:
is this the right way to handle this?
If no, could you suggest other means?
if yes, how do i go about specifying the migrations?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the Migration with the -ContextTypeName flag?

Add-Migration PatientMigration -ContextTypeName PatientContextname

Comment: No I haven't. Could you direct as to how to do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Add-Migration [MigrationName] -ContextTypeName [ContextName]

Comment: Thanks. I will try it now and get back to you.

Comment: I think if it works, it will only be temporary.  I will post a detailed answer on handling multiple contexts in migrations.

Comment: -ContextTypeName ClientDbContext

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469881/how-do-i-enable-ef-migrations-for-multiple-contexts-to-separate-databases

Comment: Be sure to look at both the first and second answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130730/discussion-between-dan-orlovsky-and-onotseike).

Comment: Using multiple contexts for the same database can create problems when using Entity Framework Code First to create the database.  Can this be the problem?  Is there a reason you can't use AspNet's RoleManager to create a Doctor & Patient role, and separate them that way?

Comment: I will look into the role Manager better. Many Thanks Dan