# Entity Framework code first migrations for two different databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am quite confused with a situation here. I need to connect to two separate databases, one is a SQL Server database and the other is a MySQL database.

I have the connection strings in the `web.config` file. I am able to connect to the servers and access data.

But, I need to run entity migration on both the servers simultaneously. Or one by one, which I don't think is possible.

Here is my database context:

```
// Database 1
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("name=OldDBContext"){ }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { }

    public static DatabaseContext Create()
    {
        return new DatabaseContext();
    }

    public DbSet<User> UserModel { get; set; }
}

// Database 2
public class NewDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public NewDatabaseContext() : base("name=NewDBContext") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { }

    public static NewDatabaseContext Create()
    {
        return new NewDatabaseContext();
    }

    public DbSet<UserData> UserDataModel { get; set; }
}
```

Initially I had only one database and I used to run `add-migration MigrationName` in the package manager console and it would create a migration with the changes in the database.

But now, when I have two separate databases, the migrations does not contain any changes in the second database or the one I added later.

Please help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How are you registering the two DbContexts in your Startup file? Also, are you wanting both databases to update when data is changed?

Comment: @KidCode I have not registred any database in global.asax. when I had only one database, I guess it was not necessary.

Comment: @KidCode I want to update the database schema like when I do `update-database` or `add-migration` but only one db is getting updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to enable migrations for second context, use ContextTypeName parameter

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -ContextTypeName
NamespaceOfContext.NewDatabaseContext
```

It will create separate configuration. If naming conflicts occured rename configuration file in Migrations folder, then you can run database update for specific configuration

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName ConfigurationName
```

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469881/how-do-i-enable-ef-migrations-for-multiple-contexts-to-separate-databases question