# Migrations Configuration Type was not found in the assembly

Tags: entity-framework

I have different DbContexts that connects to different database. My first two DbContexts works fine when adding migration but the last DbContext (FinalPmisDbContext) that I have added couldn't add a migration. I have tried these two commands in the PM

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName SosaPmisApi.Models.FinalPmisDbContext -Force
```

this is the result I get:

```
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Code First Migrations enabled for project SosaPmisApi.
```

Then I run this command:

```
add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName SosaPmisApi.Migrations.FinalPmisDbContext.Configuration "AddedPropertySoa"
```

But I get this error:
The migrations configuration type '`SosaPmisApi.Migrations.FinalPmisDbContext.Configuration' was not be found in the assembly 'SosaPmisApi'.`

This is my DbContext:

```
using SosaPmisApi.Models.FinalCurtain;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SosaPmisApi.Models
{
    public class FinalPmisDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public FinalPmisDbContext() : base("RevisionConnection") { }

        public DbSet<PropertySoaDates> PropertySoaDates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I can see a Configuration.cs that has this..

```
namespace SosaPmisApi.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SosaPmisApi.Models.FinalPmisDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SosaPmisApi.Models.FinalPmisDbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a class of DbMigrationsConfiguration when you want to use the parameter ConfigurationTypeName

Comment: What do you mean? I have a configuration.cs that extends internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SosaPmisApi.Models.FinalPmisDbContext>

Comment: can you show that class too pls?

Comment: Please see my  update.

Comment: Probabaly the Configuration.cs was created during my enable-migration -Force.

Comment: can you try it with the following command -ConfigurationTypeName SosaPmisApi.Migrations.Configuration

Comment: I get this error: `Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201806151312541_DatabaseCreation, 201806151315346_ChangedIdentityTableNames]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.`

Comment: to resolve the error you have to run the command -update-database

Comment: But those are for my first migrations. When I created my `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: you have 2 DbContext-Classes in your project?

Comment: It somehow overwrote my migrations for those database.

Comment: I had 2 before. Then I added this one.

Comment: And how many do you have now? 3? Any way may have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469881/how-do-i-enable-ef-migrations-for-multiple-contexts-to-separate-databases

Comment: So now I have three. But the third one has overwritten my migration history for my very first one.

Comment: When I created my DbContext, it automatically created a folder and all the migration history was placed on that folder. Why is it now, on my third migration, it does not. It took the space of my first migration. How do I place it in a folder as well so all migrations can be placed in that folder? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Sorry I dont know. I only work once mit multiple context and I have do it the same way as in the link I post.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It led me somewhere.