# how to add more than 1 context in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one `UserContext`.

```
    public class UserContext:DbContext
    {
        public UserContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
            var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
            objectContext.CommandTimeout = 2 * 60; 
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ExternalUserInformation> ExternalUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
     }
```

I want to have second context `PaymentContext` where I will put `DbSet`s about payments.

```
    public class PaymentContext:DbContext
    {
        public PaymentContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
            var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
            objectContext.CommandTimeout = 2 * 60; 
        }

        public DbSet<PaymentLog> PaymentLogs { get; set; }

     }
```

My question is: How to do it? Why if I have these 2 context, command `update-database` doesn't work properly? (only one context is updating database - this first. Second not).

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 4.3 Auto-Migrations with multiple DbContexts in one database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110536/ef-4-3-auto-migrations-with-multiple-dbcontexts-in-one-database)

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10009491/1814343) is what you're looking for.

If you want to have more than one dbcontext, you should create configuration classes for each dbcontext.