# EF6, Code First Migration - does not create foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-framework-migrations

I first created following classes and updated to database, tables are created already.

```
public class Region
{
   public int RegionId { get; set; }
   public string RegionName { get; set; }
}

public class Zone
{
    public int ZoneId { get; set; }
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }
}
```

after i needed to insert foreign key into table Zone:

```
public class Zone
 {
    public int ZoneId { get; set; }
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

tried: add-migration zone, and update-database.. it is not updating database. And Add-Migration is creating class with empty properties Up() & Down().
Also tried to add [ForeignKey("RegionId")] with no success.
What I am doing wrong ?

EDIT:
this is last version which is working:

```
public class Region
{
   public int RegionId { get; set; }
   public string RegionName { get; set; } 
}
public class Zone
{
    public int ZoneId { get; set; }
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }
    public int  RegionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

Also I had two Contexts, and found solution here (Answer of **Brice**) - [EF 4.3 Auto-Migrations with multiple DbContexts in one database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110536/ef-4-3-auto-migrations-with-multiple-dbcontexts-in-one-database)

Comment: tried following:    public class Region
    {
       public int RegionId { get; set; }
       public string RegionName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones {get; set; } 
    }

    public class Zone
    {
        public int ZoneId { get; set; }
        public string ZoneName { get; set; }
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public Region Region { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Are you sure that migration is enabled?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. becuase I am doing with Code First. and other tables are updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to learn "Code First" with an existing database...is to use the EF Power Tools.

And "reverse engineer".

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

I learned more about how Mapping's work with this tool in 30 minutes, then I did with hours of googling.

Basically, create a "class library", and when this plugin is installed, you get a new context menu (on the project), that will allow you to reverse-engineer a database...

I love this tool.

Having said that, I usually see the FK scalar (of the parent) on the child object.

```
public class Zone
 {
    public int ZoneId { get; set; }
    public string ZoneName { get; set; }

    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

But a more basic question is how are you doing your mappings?

Comment: thanks for suggestion, will download and learn that tool. putting code in comments is not looking nice, anyway: public class SiteContext : DbContext
    {
        public SiteContext()
            : base("RID")
        { }  public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Zone> Zones { get; set; } }

Comment: Deleted related tables from DB and run project, now tables are created in correct way as I want. tnx

Comment: Maybe append your question with the final code........(leave the original question intact).  It's hard to see what is happening in the comments area (when its code).  Glad it worked out.